# Running into a "A name parameter is required to create storage" when creating Apex Class w/ VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, vs-code

I'm attempting to create an Apex Class a part of the Convert Lightning Web Components Open Source to Salesforce trailhead module and when I try to create a class on my mac, I run into this error.

sfdx force:apex:class:create --classname SessionController --template DefaultApexClass -n SessionController  --outputdir force-app/main/default/classes
ERROR running force:apex:class:create:  A name parameter is required to create a storage

Comment: Getting the same thing now when creating a project. When running with --json you can at least get a stack trace, trying to look at the code to see if I can find a root cause...

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/253

Using that issue discussion as reference. I would check that you don't have some package.json file without any name attribute in the root folder of the system directory.

Otherwise, even adding package.json with the name attribute seems to be the other suggested workaround

```
{
    "name": "<anything>"
}
```

Comment: So apparently the problem is that if you have a `package.json` in *any* of the parent directories of the directory you're trying to create a new project from, you get this error. I had a `package.json` in `../..` and deleted it,and that fixed it.

Comment: Not sure if you checked before deleting, but did that "other" `package.json` have no `name` attribute?

Comment: I did not check, but I assume it didn't.